# Sphinx cannot find module during make html, but parent folder of package is on path

Tags: python, python-import, python-sphinx, autodoc

Note: edited to reflect name change from `gui.py` to `neuro_gui.py`

Here is my project structure:

```
gui
├── src
│   └── gui
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── neuro_gui.py
│       └── listen.py
└── docs
    ├── _build
    ├── conf.py
    └── etc
```

In my `conf.py` I do:

```py
import os 
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/'))
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon']
napoleon_google_docstring = False
```

In the root `gui` directory, I do the command: `sphinx-apidoc -o docs src\gui src\gui\ui_*`

This generates a `gui.rst` and `modules.rst` in docs.

Then I do `make html` in the `docs` directory. Here sphinx properly creates documentation for `listen.py`. But in `neuro_gui.py`, I have the following import:
`from listen import Listener`

This is causing issues; Sphinx says

WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'gui' from module 'gui'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'listen'

I tried doing relative imports (i.e. `from .listen import listener`) and this fixed the issue with sphinx, however it broke the script itself. I also tried adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` to my `__init__.py` and using absolute imports, but this resulted in the same behavior (i.e. docs generate fine but script breaks).

To be more specific, as suggested in a comment: it says `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui'` if I do `from gui.listen import listener` and `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` with `from .listen import listener` Both of these changes cause Sphinx to work properly but break the script

I have also discovered that the `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` in `conf.py` has no effect, I only need the `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src/'))` line.

Would appreciate any input; I am pretty inexperienced with Sphinx and I have tried the suggestions from many other threads re: this issue, but none worked so far

Comment: gui.py complains about the relative/absolute imports

Comment: it says `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui'` if I do `from gui.listen import listener` and `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` with `from .listen import listener` Both of these changes cause Sphinx to work properly but break the script
(was trying to add but apparently you can only edit comments for 5 minutes..????)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing my `__init__.py` to:

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(''))
import gui.listen
import gui.neuro_gui
```

Then in all my source files I used relative imports.

Following that, instead of running the source files directly I import their contents into a `main.py` at the `src` directory, and run the program there. Sphinx is able to document the code and I am able to run it properly. The fact that Python makes it very difficult to run classes/code from a module in the same module is irritating and probably my least favorite feature of the language!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `from gui.listen import listener` in `gui.py`?

If that doesn't work either, the issue is most likely that you have `gui` as the name of both the package and the module. Try changing either of those.

Comment: Tried renaming gui.py to neuro_gui.py and still having the same issue, I also tried this with the `from gui.listen import listener` before and after this change.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by having `gui` as the name of both the package and the module? Do you mean the name of the script, as I initially interpreted it?